# Why PyCharm inspector shows type warning when I use operator.itemgetter with sorted function?

Tags: python, pycharm

Consider the following simple Python code:

```
from operator import itemgetter


def main():

    my_list = [
        ('Bob', 'RnD', 10),
        ('John', 'RnD', 11),
        ('Mary', 'Sales', 10),
        ('Linda', 'Sales', 11),
    ]
    # I saw a lot of examples tell people to do multi-fields sorting like this, but 
    # PyCharm inspector warns it
    print(sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter(1, 2), reverse=True))
    # I read some articles and found that the following code works, too, without warning.
    print(sorted(my_list, key=(lambda x: (x[1], x[2])), reverse=True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the line "print(sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter(1, 2), reverse=True))", PyCharm shows the following warning:

> Expected type '(Tuple[str, str, int]) -> Any' (matched generic type '(_T) -> Any'), got 'itemgetter' instead more... (Ctrl+F1)

When I click 'more', it shows:

> Expected type '(Tuple[str, str, int]) -> Any' (matched generic type
>   '(_T) -> Any'), got 'itemgetter' instead less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due
>   to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but
>   useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified
>   in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.

[image]

Both code (both itemgetter and lambda) work well, just code inspection warning.

So my questions are:

- Why PyCharm inspector warns me with this?
- Is it worth to be fixed? and how to fix it with itemgetter?
- Shall I suppress such warning for all my projects?
- Shall I always use the next line (with lambda statement) for such sorting?

Comment: which version are you using? i'm on `2018.1` and everything is fine

Comment: PyCharm 2018.1 EAP (Community Edition)
Build #PC-181.3870.25, built on February 21, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b11 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

Comment: and Python version?

Comment: sometimes it helps to just reload IDE

Comment: I have the same problem with you. I'm using PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-182.4505.26, built on September 19, 2018